# How to use ProGard for PhoneGap android project?

Tags: android, cordova, apk, obfuscation

What are the different ways to obfuscate phoengap application apk file.

Comment: Proguard can obfuscate only java. Am I right that Phonegap uses HTML/JS?

Comment: Thanks. But any other ways available to obfuscate phonegap apk.

Comment: Please answer my question first.

Comment: APK can't be obfuscated. Only the source code can be. And to tell you how to obfuscate the source code, I need you to tell me which language it is written in.

Comment: Yes, you are right. PhoneGap uses HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: then you need to obfuscate Javascript and HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: Try this plugin: https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file

Comment: I try you suggested plugin.

Comment: But not feasible. Any other plugin available?